# Handlebar helper and .toLocaleString

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I display results of a json in Handlebars including numbers that I'd like to format with .toLocaleString().
My json sample:

```
[{"id": "1",
 "results": [{
     "price": 5000
      },
      {
     "price": 6000
  }]
  },
  {"id": "2",
 "results": [{
     "price": 15000
      },
      {
     "price": 16000
      }]
  }]...
```

Then I render it with Express in the backend and Handlebars in front:

```
{{#each results as |auction|}}                    

     <span class="results__container--price">{{auction.price}} €</span>
{{/each}}
```

(In reality, it's more complexe)

But I don't know how to use toLocaleString(). Maybe I have to loop through "prices in Express but I don't know how to do it. Is it possible to use it directly with Handlebars ?

Comment: Did you try `{{auction.price.toLocaleString()}}`

Comment: Yes and it doesn't work. Handlebars doesn't seem to work that way

Comment: Use a helper function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a helper function

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper('toLocaleString', function(number) {
  return number.toLocaleString()
})


var source = document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML;
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var context = {
  title: "Hello",
  count: 123456789
};
var html = template(context);

document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.1.2/handlebars.min.js"></script>

<script id="temp" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  <div class="test">
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
    <h2>{{toLocaleString count}}
  </div>
</script>

<div id="out"></div>
```

Comment: I just didi this before your answer and that's good ! Thank you !